# How do I get the short, local date/time format with Swift 4.0?

Tags: swift, xcode

I am trying to print a date (e.g. a birthdate) using the following code (swift 4.0, Xcode 10.2):

```
    let formatter = DateFormatter()
    formatter.timeStyle = .short
    formatter.dateStyle = .short
    formatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_US")
    formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm"
    let DOB = formatter.date(from: "2019/05/01 22:30")
```

when print(DOB) I got, **"2019-05-02 05:30:00 +0000"**

It looks like none of the Local, `.short` settings affected the results.

What's wrong. How do I get to simply print: "2019/05/01 22:30"?

Comment: You have a `Date` object, it's not localized, it's just a fancy unix timestamp. Youneed to use again a `DateFormatter` to have a localized representation string of it as youwant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are currently doing is converting a string to a `Date`. `Date`s don't contain information about how they are displayed. They are printed all the same way: 2019-05-02 05:30:00 +0000.

*Strings* have formats, so you should convert the `Date` you just got, back to a string using a date formatter. Basically, you have two formatters: one for converting the string to a date, and another for converting the date back to a string

```
let stringToDateformatter = DateFormatter()
stringToDateformatter.dateFormat = "yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm"
let DOB = stringToDateformatter.date(from: "2019/05/01 22:30")

let dateToStringFormatter = DateFormatter()
dateToStringFormatter.timeStyle = .short
dateToStringFormatter.dateStyle = .short
dateToStringFormatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_US")
let DOBString = dateToStringFormatter.string(from: DOB!)
print(DOBString) // 5/1/19, 10:30 PM
```

Comment: Thank you. It works. I assume if I need to use the date for future use, e.g. computing an age, I will need to stay with the date format, i.e. DOB but not DOBstring.

Answer (score -1):

```
    let formatter = DateFormatter()
    formatter.timeStyle = .short
    formatter.dateStyle = .short
    formatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_US")
    formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm"
    let DOB = formatter.date(from: "2019/05/01 22:30")

    formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm"
let createdDate = formatter.string(from: DOB!)
```

Comment: If its work then please upvote and accept my answer so other releted user can find easily