# How to get only time from date in swift

Tags: ios, swift, date, timestamp

This question is not asked for the first time, but no solution works for me. I am getting time in String from Api response in the following format "14:45".
I want to compare this time with the current time, for this purpose I need to convert this string in Time formate(swift sports)
I always get `nil` after conversion
I have tried multiple ways but none of them worked for me and one is given for reference, I don't know what am I missing here

Thanks for any response

```
     func stringToTime(str:String) -> Date{ // 14:45 passed here in str
        let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
        dateFormatter.dateFormat = "hh:mm a"
        print(str)
        //here time string prints
        let date = dateFormatter.date(from: (str))
        print(date)
        //date is nil here, should be 02:45 pm
        return date!

}
```

Comment: looks like you specified am/pm in your format but you left that out of your str

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems like you want to transform a time string in one format to another format. Your method signature should look like this:

```
func changeFormat(str:String) -> String {
```

Note that you should not output a `Date` here, because [`Date`s don't have formats](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55947222/5133585). They will always be printed in the same way. What you need to do in this method is 2 things:

- parse `str` to a `Date` using a `DateFormatter`, specifying the format `HH:mm`. You seem to assume that `DateFormatter` can automatically work this format out. It can't :(
- format the `Date` object you just got using a `DateFormatter`, specifying the format `hh:mm a`. This produces a string, not a date.

(You could also consider having the method return a `Date` (then it would be called `parseTime`), and do the second step *just before you show the date to the screen*.)

```
func changeFormat(str:String) -> String {
    let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()

    // step 1
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "HH:mm" // input format
    let date = dateFormatter.date(from: str)!

    // step 2
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "hh:mm a" // output format
    let string = dateFormatter.string(from: date)
    return string
}
```

Answer (score 4):

If the time you get from the API is in 24h format you can do a string comparison

```
let formatter = DateFormatter()
formatter.dateFormat = "HH:mm"
let currentTime = formatter.string(from: Date())

let compare = currentTime.compare("14:45")
```

You might need to set the time zone for the DateFormatter to make sure it uses the same as the API